# Why does Socket.io server override node http middleware?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have made a React application which relies fully on WebSockets after the initial HTTP Upgrade. For security reasons i use a cookie AND a JWT token in my WebSockets connection.

It all works fine, but when opening a new tab, socket.io cookies get reissued and I want users to stay logged in over multiple tabs. So i want to set a cookie if the client doesn't already have one. If it already has one, then use that cookie.

So I want to handle the first HTTP polling requests and created middleware for that in Node's http server:

```
// HTTP SERVER
const server = require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log('test');
  console.log(request);

  if(!request.headers.cookie) { // cookie pseudo-logic
    response.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
}

// Socket.IO server instance
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  origins: config.allowedOrigins,
  cookie: false, // disable default io cookie
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

I use Socket.io as WebSockets framework. The problem however is that this middleware get's ignored, when registering the Socket.io server. When i comment out the Socket.io server, the middleware is active and the request get's logged.

It looks like Socket.io's server is overriding the handler for node http's server. In the Socket.io docs however they provide this example:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Thus indicating that it should be possible to handle thw first http polling requests and also the socket requests. I managed to get it work with Express, but I don't understand why node's http server can't.

Anybody who knows what's happening?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Use [socket.io middleware](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#namespaceusefn) instead.  That will allow you to participate in the initial socket.io connection.  That's what it is there for.

Comment: I know, but i want to implement logic which decides if a cookie needs to be set or not. If client already sent a cookie, then no new cookie will be set. If not, then set a new cookie. It's not possible to set cookie from socket.io. So i want to handle the request before even a WebSocket connection is established. I managed however to do it with Express middleware, but I don't understand why it doesn't work with Node's http server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because normal usage of socket.io does not want regular http middleware to see socket.io connection requests (they would normally trigger 404 responses), socket.io places its own request handler first in line before any others, even ones that existed before it was installed.

You can see how it does that here: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/server.js#L437 in the engine.io source.

I can think of the following ways for you to pre-process a request before socket.io sees it:

1. Use a proxy and do your cookie stuff in a proxy before socket.io even sees the request.
2. Patch socket.io/engine.io code to add a callback hook for what you want to do.
3. Copy the technique used by socket.io/engine.io to put your own request handler first in line after socket.io is configured.
4. Find a way to override the socket.io server object's `handleRequest()` method which is what gets called when there's an incoming connection request.  You can see its code [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/server.js#L216).

Comment: @Maikkeyy - Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks. I forgot to respond. To clarify it for myself: What do you exactly mean with using a proxy? First letting users visit another port(proxy) on the webserver and handle authentication there and then open a WebSockets connection after succesful auth? Because this can also be done on the same domain, right, like I am trying in the example. Authentication is then first handled over HTTP and then a WebSockets channel is opened. That it works with express, can that mean that socket.io does not overwrite the request handler from Express?

Comment: @Maikkeyy - I just meant a proxy sitting in front of your server can transparently do anything it wants to an incoming connection before your server sees it and then, if appropriate, let it through to your server (either modified or unmodified).  It's one type of architecture for solving issues like this.  It probably wouldn't be my first choice in this case because you can probably solve your issue with one of the other options.  I'd probably start by investigating option 4.

Comment: Ah okayy, i understand. Thank you! A downside of option 2 could be the maintainability right? Because when you update socket.io as dependency it could overwrite your callback hook? The callback hook would then be for example re-adding the node http's request listener as they remove all request listeners in the source you provided?

Comment: @Maikkeyy - Yes, option 2 would probably be my last choice for maintainability reasons.  Much better to use one of the other options.  I would personally look at option 4 first and then option 3 because both can hopefully be done on the existing server without modifying socket.io code.